# IE adds a scrollbar to input type="text"

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8, input

In my GWT application I have some text boxes. Nothing special, just

```
<input type="text" tabindex="4" class="gwt-TextBox">
```

In IE 8 I have a strange behaviour: If the containing text is longer that the text box, a horizontal scroll bar is displayed inside the box (and yes, the scroll bar hides the text).

In Firefox everything's fine. Why is that? Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause! In my stylesheet I had the following:

```
.dialog input[type="text"],
.dialog input[type="password"],
.dialog textarea {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

which is [a fix for a Firefox-Bug](http://www.bram.us/2007/05/31/my-note-to-myself-dissapearing-firefox-caret-cursor-css-fix/) :-)